# Mostrar números de semana según un rango dinámico

Tags: sql, transact-sql

agradeceré su gran apoyo absolviéndome una incidencia que me tiene confundido, sucede que requiero mostrar una serie de datos que están dentro de un rango de 2 variables, y quisiera que se muestre en una sola consulta, sin embargo, al ejecutarlo se me muestran los datos en distintas consultas.
El query que uso es similar a este:

```
declare @sem_corte int = (select max(num_semana) from bi_dvy_tbl_cli_vig_h)
declare @sem_inicio int = (select max(num_semana) - 5 from bi_dvy_tbl_cli_vig_h)
declare @query nvarchar(200)

while @sem_inicio < @sem_corte
begin

set @sem_inicio = @sem_inicio+1

set @query = 'select '+cast(@sem_inicio as nvarchar(100))+', from @tbl_prueba'
print @query

end
```

como resultado obtengo lo siguiente:

```
select 19, from @tbl_prueba
select 20, from @tbl_prueba
select 21, from @tbl_prueba
select 22, from @tbl_prueba
select 23, from @tbl_prueba
```

Quisiera que mi salida de información sea similar a este:

```
select 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 from @tbl_prueba
```

podrían ayudarme indicándome que estoy realizando mal?

Comment: ¿Quieres mostrar una cantidad dinámica de columnas según un parámetro? ¿Por qué no está normalizada esa tabla?

Comment: Hola, si esta normalizada, solo que me interesaría ver un evolutivo mensual por semana, por tal motivo estoy tratando de implementar este query...

Comment: La estructura de mi tabla es:

| anio | mes | semana | fec_corte  | idsegmento | nomsegmento | qcasos |
| ---- | --- | ------ | ---------- | ---------- | ----------- | ------ |
| 2022 | 06  | 23     | 2022-06-06 |     1      | Light       | 4534   |
| 2022 | 06  | 22     | 2022-05-30 |     4      | Heavy       | 2015   |
*
*
*
*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la parte de tu "while" necesitas hacer algo así:

```
set @query='select '+cast(@sem_inicio as nvarchar(10))
while @sem_inicio < @sem_corte
begin

set @sem_inicio = @sem_inicio+1

set @query+=' ,'+cast(@sem_inicio as nvarchar(10))

end

set @query+=' from @tbl_prueba'

print @query
```

en vez de "print" puedes usar el "sp_sqlexec" para sql server y ejecutarlo como un query, espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Hola, hice algunas adecuaciones al código y me funciono perfecto...muchas gracias...!!!

Comment: Excelente, me ayudarías mucho marcando la respuesta como "correcto" si te ayudo mi respuesta.